# Spring LocalResolver based on query parameter 'lang=en'?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Can I tell `spring-boot` to automatically resolve the requested `locale` by a queryparameter, eg `&lang=en`?

I would like to give the query param precedence over `Accept-Language` parameter.

I found the following two properties, but nothing about a query param.

```
spring.mvc.locale= # Locale to use. By default, this locale is overridden by the "Accept-Language" header.
spring.mvc.locale-resolver=accept-header # Define how the locale should be resolved.
```

I tried as follows, which gives an exception:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   @Bean
   public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
       LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
       lci.setParamName("lang");
       return lci;
   }

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
       registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
   }
}
```

Results in:

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy`

Comment: Spring Boot == Spring Framework. So [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-localeresolver) still applies. So yes.

Comment: So and how exactly can I use a query param to set the locale? The docs only states that a query param `format` can be used to set the response output format.

Comment: You also need a different `LocaleResolver`.

Comment: And which one would I have to use instead?? Because  `spring.mvc.locale-resolver` offers ony `accept-header` or `fixed`, which is both not what I want.

Comment: As stated Spring Boot == Spring Framework. Just define your own `LocaleResolver` as you would in a regular spring application.

Comment: Yes, that's clear. I see there is LocaleResolver.setLocale(..). The question is how to implement that method so that the local is changed for the users' threads?

Comment: Is `LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(locale)` correct here?

Comment: No you don't... again read the documentation... You must register a different `LocaleResolver`... Check the implementations... DOn't guess, read. Hint check the implementations of [`LocaleResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html) there are 4 different ones to choose from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is probably as follows. Still I find the setup very counterintuitive. Especially I would have expected that:

- the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` registers itself, but does not and have to call `addInterceptors()` explicit
- the `spring.mvc.locale` parameter is still set into the custom LocaleResolver, but does not and have to override manually from `WebMvcProperties`

If all of this is desired, the docs might probably need more explanation on this.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   @Bean
   public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
       LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
       lci.setParamName("lang");
       return lci;
   }

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
       registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
   }

   @Bean
   public AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver(WebMvcProperties mvcProperties) {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver() {
            @Override
            public void setLocale(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) {
                LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(locale);
            }
        };

        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(mvcProperties.getLocale());
        return localeResolver;
    }
}
```

---

**Update improved version after discussion:**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   @Bean
   public AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver(WebMvcProperties mvcProperties) {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver() {
        @Override
        public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String locale = request.getParameter("lang");
            return locale != null
                    ? org.springframework.util.StringUtils.parseLocaleString(locale)
                    : super.resolveLocale(request);
        }
        };

        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(mvcProperties.getLocale());
        return localeResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are making things overly complex. Read the documentation... Register a different [`LocaleResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html) one that supports changing the locale.

Comment: Well that's exactly what I did (apart fro the fact that I inherited `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver`, so I can rely on the `accept-language` header if the query-parameter `lang` is missing. Even a different `LocaleResolver` would only change the locale by calling `LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(locale)`, so that's what I did here?

Comment: No that isn't what you did... You hacked a non modifiable strategy in a half modifiable strategy. Your solution will only work if the `lang` parameter is available.  So changing the locale will only work once and afterwards will fallback to the previous one again. As stated use one of the other strategies, see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-localeresolver for a description of available options. Hint don't use fixed or accept header but one that supports changes.

Comment: Ok we're probably misunderstanding each other. I'm not creating a webpage application, but a rest service that should output some messages based on the selected locale. Thus, the locale is "static" during one servlet request. If no lang is provided, the default fallback should be used throughout the entire user rest request. Otherwise use the query param, favored over accept-language heder..

Comment: Then why bother with the `LocaleChangeInterceptor`? Just create your own `LocaleResolver` then which does exactly that.

Comment: Because I then don't have to implement the "extract the locale parameter and update LocalContextHolder accordingly" logic, as it already exists.

Comment: That is already present in the base `AbstractLocaleResolver`. Heck extend the `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` (as you do now) and implement the `resolveLocale` method and check for the existence of the parameter. Is the same amount of code you have now in the overridden class but less hacky then you have now.

Comment: Really appreciate your help! It works as you suggested, and is probably much better than my hacky solution. Added the new solution above.

Comment: I have tested your second solution and adding `?lang=fr` gives me `: Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy`

Comment: Does this solution implies "?lang=en" parameter with each request (for not default locale)? Or just one request for swithing the locale and then it's saved somehow?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's see what happen:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy
...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.setLocale(AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.java:142) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor.preHandle(LocaleChangeInterceptor.java:154) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
...
```

After debug, you will know:

1. `accept-header` not support `preHandle`, you cannot use `LocaleChangeInterceptor`
2. `accept-header` have not any supported languages, you must add them manual. You can see this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7930).

`accept-header` only work when you set supported languages and the language match `Content-Language` from client browser.

So, you needn't use `spring.mvc.locale-resolver` or `spring.web.locale-resolver` . Now<sup>spring 5.3.2</sup>, no properties you need.

The way for your example to solve this is appending another `LocaleResolver`: <sup>[spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-localeresolver)</sup>

```java
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        return new SessionLocaleResolver();//new CookieLocaleResolver();
    }
```

And set:

```yaml
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true # SpringBoot>=2.1.0 
  web:
    locale: en # default
```